# How to get the value of first and second dimension where third dimension is a specific value in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

In a 2D NumPy array, how do I get the first and second element of those rows whose third element is 255?

`arr = np.array([[ 32, 32, 255], [21, 21, 10], [25, 27, 18]], dtype=np.uint8)`

How to find the first and second element, which in this case are both 32?

I basically want to get the coordinates that contain a certain color pixel.

Comment: that's not valid syntax

Comment: Couldn't you have instead made an edit? Just asking.

Comment: The question is really clear IMO. Please clean up all these useless comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Some slicing works:

```
>>> arr[arr[:,-1] == 255][:, :2]
array([[32, 32]], dtype=uint8)
```